# Browser not saving cookies but Set-Cookie headers present

Tags: django, cookies, header, fetch

I am using React frontend and Django backend and have been struggling for days with authentication. I have boiled down the issue I am having to the browser not setting the cookies it receives from the backend.

When in inspect, I can verify that the Set-Cookie headers are present in the response. They are not appearing in storage though... (the cookies are a csrf token and session id). Other functionalities dependant on these cookies like logout fail. However, when using the Django rest framework interfaces (connecting to the backend urls, e.g., localhost:8000/users/login/), I can perform the login and over there, the cookies appear in storage.

I have tried both fetch and axios, I have included credentials: 'include' and withCredentials: true respectively.

As a final note, when using fetch, I grab the response

```
fetch(url, { ... })
.then(res => console.log(res.headers.get('Set-Cookie')))
```

When this prints null, when looping over all present headers I only see two (like application json).

For reference some screenshots.

[image: storage]

These are all the cookies present, I am expecting to see csrftoken and session.

The next image shows the headers, there are two Set-Cookie headers with both sessionid and csrftoken.

[image: headers]

And finally the cookies from the response

[image: cookies]

I have enabled the cors settings in Django, I played around with all pf the SAMESITE and HTTPONLY settings for cookies, I also tried different cors settings, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the browser to accept cookies with **samesite=none**, then they must also have the **secure** attribute set and you must use **HTTPS**.

Like

```
Set-Cookie:SessionCookie=xxxxxxxxxx; SameSite=None; Secure;
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:[Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to “mimic https” in development? I am still working on localhost, both frontend and backend but I am in the process of getting a certificate. I am quite new to this, so should both frontend and backend be on https for this to work (I realise this is a mist when the site is deployed, but again, I am still on an early stage)?

Comment: Everything that touches the browser should be HTTPS today, even for local development. Otherwise things will break if you use HTTP locally. On the backend, internally, you can use HTTP. You can use HTTPS with localhost, if you creat ea development certificate.

Comment: I have followed this quick and easy guide https://timonweb.com/django/https-django-development-server-ssl-certificate/, I now have a local certificate setup and can use https connection. Cookies are being stored in the browser when received from the server.

Comment: There is still one aspect I don't quite get, now I get the following error when I enable the credentials (i.e., credentials: 'include'): {"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."}. I have found a post that suggested to set the X-CSRFToken header, I just don't see to what value since I cannot access the cookie from javascript...

Comment: The CSRF token is typically injected into the HTML page forms by the web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this lastnight

### Front end

you should add `withCredentials :true` for fetch or axios

A document about [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

### Back end

Make sure you set the response header like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000, etc...
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

[Reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) why shouldn't set wildcard for origin

And you should add `SameSite=None` for cookies

### Infrastructure

Because my backend hosting in azure, it block CORS with credentials by default. So if all above not work, better check your host

Comment: By the way, you do not need access cookie in your javascript client, you just need stored it in client, and client's browser will do rest of work

Reason [why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is maybe not clear from my post, but I did everything you suggested (withCredentials, origin settings in backend, etc.). I did end up needing to setup an HTTPS connection which resolved the issue partly. When I include the withCredentials option, I am unable to send the request if I do not the X-CSRFToken header, problem is that I cannot access the token to set the header from javascript. @Tore Estenius mentioned that the token is injected into the HTML page, I just don't know how to do that with react receiving html (or a form) from Django.